# ng build command is not working via jenkins build execute shell

Tags: shell, jenkins, sh, angular2-services

In jenkins build execute area I put these command:

```
cd /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test/
ng serve
```

Here is the screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

I am getting an error like this:

> - cd /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test/
> - ng serve
>
> Environment variable TERM not defined!
>
> Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure Finished: FAILURE
>
> node v6.10.0
>
> @angular/cli: 1.0.6

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Some how it started working now. Instead of " $ ng build"  have given $ npm run build. n it started building.

Answer (score 10):

Try this I did jenkins integration today.

```
npm run ng build
```

This is working fine.

Comment: Note that any build parameters will be need to be separated by --.  E.g "ng build --somesetting" requires "npm run ng build -- --somesetting"

Comment: @DarrylC Your comment helped :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case my slave Jenkins was working as Docker container and there was no global @angular/cli installation but in node_modules.

[image]

[image]

That's why I wanted to call `ng` command from `@angular/cli/bin/ng`. To able this I needed to add path of ng into PATH environment variable:
[image]

And the result:
[image]

Otherwise I will have to install angular cli in docker globally.