# Jenkins ng command not found

Tags: angular, jenkins

Below are the Nodejs and Angular CLI version which are running in my windows 10 machine.

Angular CLI: 8.3.5
Node: 10.16.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 8.2.7

I have created jenkins job to build Angular Application in my localhost.

Question is here, When i running jenkins job (Freestyle) based project, using this command "C:\Angular>npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest && ng v" first install command is working perfectly without any issue, but when its moving to next command "ng v" its throughout the error as like below:

'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

Note: But same cmd "npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest && ng v" is working as we expected in powershell.

Can you please some help on this.

Comment: try to have two separated steps . So one with the first command and one with the ng v command . Im guessing the && is causing this issue . This doesnt happen in case of a pipeline but for freestyle you might see it. give it a try

Comment: Hi We have tried to export our ng model path in pipeline script and result is working as expected pipeline 

 stage('Test') {
      steps {
         bat 'C:/Angular/node_modules/.bin/ng test --watch=false --code-coverage'
      }
    }

Comment: Note : without C:/Angular/node_modules/.bin/ this module path it is not working. Can you please suggest how to fix this.

Comment: did you actually setup angular in the global configuration in jenkins? If not see this article https://medium.com/@gustavo.guss/jenkins-starting-with-pipeline-doing-a-node-js-test-72c6057b67d4

Comment: Its working now, after updating global configuration as well.

Comment: glad that it worked!

Comment: I just wanted to share my previous answer which may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61521790/104085

Answer (score 5):

npm command is recognized by default, but "ng" don't, so that you have to write "npm run" before ng command:

```
npm run ng .....
```