# Jenkins on ec2 not recognizing composer or npm - both are installed

Tags: jenkins

I've installed Jenkins on an Amazon ec2 instance according to the instructions here https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/linux/#red-hat-centos and when I try to run a job that has an execute shell command step that does "composer install" or "npm install" it isn't recognizing either command.  However from the terminal (as ec2-user) I can run both.  Is there something I need to do to let Jenkins know where to find these commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized I can sudo su jenkins and install composer as that user.

For NPM, [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45914038/jenkins-unable-to-find-npm) helped.  You need to install the nodejs plugin, restart Jenkins, then in the build environment section of the configuration of your job, choose "Provide Node & npm bin/ folder to PATH".

I was still having problems running ng commands - after installing the ng client as the jenkins user.  This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58084437/jenkins-ng-command-not-found) helped - which says to add "npm run" before ng.

I hope this helps someone.  Especially since I figured it out moments after offering my bounty!